# Converting date back to JSON time using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

so i have a JSON time for example 786668400 which i'm converting to day, month, year to display on a page. i have a form with select boxes for users to insert their birthdate and i need to submit the form with the result of those 3 select boxes in JSON time (or whatever it's called) using jquery/javascript.

how do i do that?

edit: adding some code as was asked by users...

i'm converting it to a normal date using jquery like so:
    var dateFormat = new Date(786668400*1000).getDate() + "." + (new Date(786668400*1000).getMonth() + 1) + "." + new Date(786668400*1000).getFullYear();

these are the select boxes for the birthdate

```
<select name="day"><option>Day</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7" selected="">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option></select><select name="month"><option>Month</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10" selected="">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option></select><select name="year"><option>Year</option><option value="1941">1941</option><option value="1942">1942</option><option value="1943">1943</option><option value="1944">1944</option><option value="1945">1945</option><option value="1946">1946</option><option value="1947">1947</option><option value="1948">1948</option><option value="1949">1949</option><option value="1950">1950</option><option value="1951">1951</option><option value="1952">1952</option><option value="1953">1953</option><option value="1954">1954</option><option value="1955">1955</option><option value="1956">1956</option><option value="1957">1957</option><option value="1958">1958</option><option value="1959">1959</option><option value="1960">1960</option><option value="1961" selected="">1961</option><option value="1962">1962</option><option value="1963">1963</option><option value="1964">1964</option><option value="1965">1965</option><option value="1966">1966</option><option value="1967">1967</option><option value="1968">1968</option><option value="1969">1969</option><option value="1970">1970</option><option value="1971">1971</option><option value="1972">1972</option><option value="1973">1973</option><option value="1974">1974</option><option value="1975">1975</option><option value="1976">1976</option><option value="1977">1977</option><option value="1978">1978</option><option value="1979">1979</option><option value="1980">1980</option><option value="1981">1981</option><option value="1982">1982</option><option value="1983">1983</option><option value="1984">1984</option><option value="1985">1985</option><option value="1986">1986</option><option value="1987">1987</option><option value="1988">1988</option><option value="1989">1989</option><option value="1990">1990</option><option value="1991">1991</option><option value="1992">1992</option><option value="1993">1993</option><option value="1994">1994</option><option value="1995">1995</option><option value="1996">1996</option><option value="1997">1997</option><option value="1998">1998</option><option value="1999">1999</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2002">2002</option><option value="2003">2003</option><option value="2004">2004</option><option value="2005">2005</option><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2011">2011</option><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2013">2013</option><option value="2014">2014</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2016">2016</option></select>
```

and i need to get the values of these select boxes and convert them back to the JSON time format.

.toJSON() doesn't seem to do it...

i have no code for this yet because i haven't found anything that does that. all that comes up is converting from JSON to date...

Comment: Suzanne, we need to see your code, post that JSON time, the form and anything else strictly useful. Click "edit" under your question and paste your code.

Comment: Do you have any code that you have currently tried that is not working? If you do, you should consider posting it and explain what you are having trouble with. Otherwise, this is a broad question that risks being closed.

Comment: @Lexi i've posted some code although i'm not supposed to. i hope this helps but i really don't think the question is that broad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert date to timestamp by creating date object and calling getTime method. Full example:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="year" value="2016">
  <input type="text" id="month" value="10">
  <input type="text" id="day" value="11">
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>

<script>
  jQuery(function() {
    var calculateTimestamp = function() {
      //Ge values from inputs
      var year = jQuery('#year').val();
      var month = jQuery('#month').val();
      var day = jQuery('#day').val();
      //Create date object. Month is 0 based
      var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day, 12);
      //Get timestamp and convert to seconds
      jQuery('#result').html(date.getTime() / 1000)
    };
    calculateTimestamp();

    jQuery('input').on('chagne, keyup', calculateTimestamp);
  });
</script>
```